# XCode 8.2 Can't connect interface builder IBOutlet to swift file

Tags: ios, swift3, storyboard, xcode8.2

I'm looking for a solution specifically for the issue with a Swift3 UIViewController having IBOutlets defined, but dragging actions from storyboard does not connect them to existing outlets. I can add new outlets, just with different name, and they work (still cant re-connect them later).

I see old solutions for objective-C dealing with headers and source files, but a swift is a single file per class.

**Is there a way to fix "can't connect IBOutlet to swift file" issue?**

Comment: Check that the "module" field below the view controller class field in your storyboard is empty.

Comment: The module is empty-current. I set it explicitly (only 1 available) and nothing changed

Comment: how about close and open xcode?

Answer (score 3):

> but dragging actions from storyboard does not connect them to existing outlets

I've noticed this too. But it's not a difficult problem. Here's what to do:

Look carefully at the gutter next to the outlet in the code. There is a circle. *Drag* from that circle (no need for control-drag) to the view in the Interface Builder canvas.

[image]